# How do I reference another collection as a field in a Meteor Schema

Tags: meteor, reference, schema

I'm using meteor simple schema, and autoform. I would like to have a reference to one type of object in the schema of the other. The two schemas are defined in separate files, I would also like to populate autoform with a dropdown of the possible references, and I'm unclear how to do this.

I've tried

```
venue:{
    type: Venues,
    label: "Venue",
},
```

and

```
venue:{
    type: SimpleSchema.Venues,
    label: "Venue",
},
```

and neither works

Comment: @Rohan-Khude I'm well aware of that, I've tried to find this in the meteor documentation and the simple schema documentation, it seems like a simple task ( simple using express and mongoose ) but not with met. It also seems like a question many meteor users would need. Also not new to stack overflow, so I'm not really sure why the comment . .

Comment: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#combining-simpleschemas

Answer (score 3):

First you have to define your schema like this:

```
VenueSchema = new SimpleSchema({
 title: {
 type: String,
 label: "Title",
 max: 200
}
})
```

Than you can in another schema declare an attribute Venue

```
CustomerSchema = new SimpleSchema({
 venue: {
 type: VenueSchema
 },
 //an array of venues
 venues: {
 type: [VenueSchema],
 minCount: 1
 }
});
```

Take a look on basic usage of simpleSchema docs -> https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#basic-usage

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think the part that confuses me is this, this seems like when I use such a structure, then use autoform, it prompts me to create the venue as I'm creating the customer ... what I really want is to be able to choose the venue from a list of existing venues that the user already created

Comment: You can list all your venue items in autoValue 
 
 `CustomerSchema = new SimpleSchema({
 venue: {
 type: VenueSchema
 },
 //an array of venues
 venues: {
 type: [VenueSchema],
 minCount: 1,
 autoValue: function () {
 return Venues.find({}).fetch()
 }
 
 }
});
`